# Bad file descriptor deploying symfony on IIS server

Tags: php, symfony, iis-7

I need to deploy an API application based on Symfony on Windows Server using IIS. I usually works with Nginx servers, but I need to work with a netFramework dll, in a machine with an ASP.NET application.

I have succesfully installed PHP on the windows server, and phpinfo() works without problem.
Also, I have uploaded all the code from Symfony (that is already tested using the Symfony Local Web Server).
But, when I try to access the main page of the project (the default Symfony page) I obtain this error:

`Notice: fwrite(): write of 163 bytes failed with errno=9 Bad file descriptor`

I have found that the exception comes from `vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Log\Logger.php`
on line 82:

`fwrite($this->handle, $formatter($level, $message, $context));`

After debugging, I have found that Symfony is trying to write into `php://stderr` data stream, so I suppose that I have a permission issue. I have try to write indifferent folders granting to IIS user writing permissions on these folders, and moving the error log configuration of PHP and IIS server to them.

Also, I can access only to the main page (the one I obtain the 500 Error), in any other route, I obtain a 404 error.

A last note, when using Postman to make a GET request to the Symfony Application I obtain a Symfony response (only in the main page, in other pages I obtain the IIS server page error)

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html If the official guide no longer lists IIS there, so you shouldn't even try.

Answer (score 4):

Change the line `path: php://stderr` to `path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"` in file `<your project>/config/packages/dev/monolog.yaml`.
Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Finally it works!

I answer myself in case someone has the same issue.

It seems that is a [bug of PHP 7.4](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79166), I have try with PHP 7.3 and works like a charm